# Why won't my pygame images load

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I'm relatively new to python and pygame, so this is most certainly just my own inexperience.  However, in my game loop, every time an image or shape is *blitted* to the screen, it doesn't disappear until another image or shape is blitzed over it.

### game_loop function

```
def game_loop():

road
carImg

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('Rally-X.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()

x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

x_change = 0

road_starty = -23
road_speed = 4

thing_starty = -600
thing_speed = 4
thing_width = 100
thing_height = 100
thing_startx = random.randrange(0, display_width)

carImgCount = 1

dodged = 0

gameExit = False

pygame.display.update()

while not gameExit:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            pygame.display.update()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d:
                x_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused()
            pygame.display.update()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                x_change = 0
            pygame.display.update()
    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.blit(road,(0,road_starty))

    car(x,y)
    #things(thingx, thingy, thingw, thingh, color)
    things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height)

    road_starty += road_speed

    thing_starty += thing_speed
    things_dodged(dodged)

    if x > display_width - car_width or x < 0:
        crash()

    if thing_starty > display_height:
        thing_starty = 0 - thing_height
        thing_startx = random.randrange(0,display_width)
        dodged += 1
        if thing_speed <= 10:
            thing_speed += 1
        pygame.display.update()

    if y < thing_starty+thing_height:
        #print('y crossover')

        if x > thing_startx and x < thing_startx + thing_width or x+car_width > thing_startx and x + car_width < thing_startx+thing_width:
            #print('x crossover')
            crash()
        pygame.display.update()
    if road_starty == 0:
        road_starty = -23

    if dodged > 9:
        things(thing_startx, thing_starty, thing_width, thing_height)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I started just calling the `pygame.display.update()` function just about everywhere in the `game_loop` function to try and fix it, but it still doesn't seem to help.

Here is a picture of the code acting up in action:
[image]

Those red lines are supposed to be squares, and the car... isn't supposed to look like that.  If someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I'm not sure why the picture isn't showing up.  I tried to upload it, but I guess it wouldn't let me.

Comment: From the picture, it looks like you're not clearing the screen between ticks.  You're using `pygame.display.update` which I'm not too familiar with, but you need to either redraw the background once something moves, or clear and redraw the whole screen every tick.  The latter is easier imo, I use `Surface.fill((0, 0, 0))`

Comment: use `pygame.display.update()` only once in loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to clear screen before you draw new frame.

```
 gameDisplay.fill((0,0,0))
```

And after clearing screen you have to draw all elements again.

You will have to reorganize you code to `fill`, `draw` and `update` in one place

You can organize `mainloop` this way (simple example)

```
# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False

        # --- objects events (without draws)---

        '''
        player.handle_event(event)
        '''

    # --- updates (without draws)---

    '''
    player.update()
    '''

    # --- draws (without updates) ---

    screen.fill(BLACK) # only once in loop

    '''
    player.draw(screen)
    '''

    pygame.display.update() # only once in loop

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(25)
```

---

full example: [PyGame simple template](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/blob/master/pygame/__template__/1__simple__.py) and [other templates](https://github.com/furas/my-python-codes/tree/master/pygame/__template__)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  That helped.  And it works now.  I can continue on with my work now.

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy, cheap way of getting the image off the screen...
 say the screen is 400 x 400 just change the coordinates of the picture to where the x is like 500 and the y is like 600 so that it is placed outside of the pygame canvas